# Python 3.7 on Debian 9 from package manager

Tags: debian, package-management, upgrade, python3

I was able to install Python 3.7 following [this instruction](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/).

```bsh
# Start by installing the packages necessary to build Python source:
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget

# Download the latest release’s source code from the Python download page using the following curl command:
$ curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz

# When download is complete, extract the tarball:
$ tar -xf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz

# Navigate to the Python source directory and run the configure script that will perform a number of checks to make sure all of the dependencies on your system are present:
$ cd Python-3.7.3
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations

# Run make to start the build process:
$ make -j 8

# Once the build is done install the Python binaries by running the following command as a user with sudo access:
$ sudo make altinstall
```

But I wonder, is there possibility to 
install (or upgrade, for example from version 3.5) Python 3.7 with package manager?

Comment: You can sometimes install newer software packages via the `backports` repository. [However, it appears Python 3.7 is not available in backports](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python%203.7&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: You can also take the next Debian's package sources, and rebuild a backported package from those sources. But you can start getting recursives tasks depending on the package: it might depend (for building, running or both) on other packages which themselves might not be available and have also to be backported the same way. And you'd have to redo this regularly to follow upgrades. https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial

Comment: The correct url showing there is no python3.7 backport for debian 9 (stretch): https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch-backports&keywords=python3.7